# Inconsistent behaviour of ffmpeg -i flag

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a Bash script that would download an audio track from youtube and convert it to Apple ringtone format, which is .m4r. The tools I employ are `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg`. The former seems to work fine but I have a strange issue with the latter. When I try to pass the name of the file parametrically, shell prints that file or directory can't be found.[image]

I use the same method for unwraping user input (or my defaults) for both commands but it only seems to work with `youtube-dl`.

Example of what doesn't work and print the text above. Obviously, all the files are in fact there and accessible

```sh
youtube-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format m4a -o $filepath_interim  --audio-quality 0 $video_link
ffmpeg -i $filepath_interim -acodec copy -f ipod -ss $offset  -t $length $filepath_out
```

So, I tried to do it with `''` strings, `$(command)` syntax, it all failed. I only found one way to make it work, which is to hard code the values of the *paths* but this defeats the whole purpose of my script.

```sh
youtube-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format m4a -o $filepath_interim  --audio-quality 0 $video_link
ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/ringtone.m4a -acodec copy -f ipod -ss $offset  -t $length ~/Downloads/ringtone.m4r
```

I want to figure out why this keeps happening, whether it is in any way specific to `ffmpeg` or am I just missing some piece of knowledge about `$` name unwrapping.

Minimal Working Example. Run with bash or pack in script and run. If your path to `bash` is different, please change the shebang:

```sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# initialise
filepath_interim="~/Downloads/ringtone.m4a"
filepath_out="~/Downloads/ringtone.m4r"
video_link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
offset=0
length=30

# main part
youtube-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format m4a -o $filepath_interim  --audio-quality 0 $video_link
ffmpeg -i $filepath_interim -acodec copy -f ipod -ss $offset  -t $length $filepath_out
```

Comment: Show the complete script.

Comment: @llogan added a full reproducible script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403187/extract-audio-to-stdout-youtube-dl  explain how to use stdout so you can pipe from youtube-dl to ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change `~` to `$HOME`

See [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and [SC2088: Tilde (~) does not expand in quotes, use $HOME](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2088) for more info.